# move contents of directory to static named subdirectory

Tags: find, mv, mkdir

I have directories of media structured as followed:

```
~ $ tree baz
baz
├── Ajin [Season 1]
│   ├── Ajin Demi-Human - 01 - A Topic That Has Nothing to Do with Us.mkv
│   ├── Ajin Demi-Human - 02 - Why Is This Happening to Me I Didn`t Do Anything Wrong!.mkv
...snip...
├── Btooom!
│   ├── Btooom! - 01 - Start.mkv
│   ├── Btooom! - 02 - The Bloodstained High School Girl.mkv
...snip...
└── Claymore [Dual Audio]
    ├── checksums.md5
    ├── Claymore - 01 - Great Sword.mkv
    ├── Claymore - 02 - The Black Card.mkv
    ├── Claymore - 03 - The Darkness in Paradise.mkv
...snip...

3 directories, 53 files
```

I need to transverse the `baz` directory and for each sub directory create a sub-sub directory named "Season 01" and place all files (and any directories) into the newly created sub-sub directory "Season 01".

Ex the above would become:

```
baz
├── Ajin [Season 1]
│   ├── Season 01
│       ├── Ajin Demi-Human - 01 - A Topic That Has Nothing to Do with Us.mkv
│       ├── Ajin Demi-Human - 02 - Why Is This Happening to Me I Didn`t Do Anything Wrong!.mkv
...snip...
etc
```

I was trying to use `find` to accomplish this, but I could not figure out how to structure the -exec command to create the "Season 01" directory, and move the contents of the directory to the new directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a simple loop.

```
cur=$(pwd)
for i in baz/*
do
    cd "$i"
    mkdir season1
    mv *.mkv season1
    cd "$cur"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for i in baz/*/*; do
  mkdir -p "${i%/*}/Season 01"
  mv "$i" "${i%/*}/Season 01"
done
```

First enable `dotglob` to also match hidden files. Then loop over the files inside the subdirectories of `baz` and

- Create the `Season 01` directory if it doesn't yet exist. The parameter expansion `${i%/*}` removes the
  filename and leaves the parent directories (e.g. `baz/Ajin [Season 1]`).
- Move the current file `"$i"` into the season directory.